# buttonWithType' is unavailable: use object construction 'UIButton(type:)

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uibutton

I have an older version of Swift and trying to do this:

```
let button = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.detailDisclosure) as UIButton
```

But get the error

> buttonWithType' is unavailable: use object construction 'UIButton(type:)

How can I solve this? I'm using Swift 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Swift 3 the syntax is the following:

```
let button = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
```